# Sending APNS from ASPX/C# Page, Authentication with SSL

Tags: c#, asp.net, ssl, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I have been trying to get a Windows 2008 R2 Datacenter(On Amazon) to utilize the Apple Push Notification Service - I've seen a lot of questions about some of this, but none of the existing answers have solved my problem.  I am writing this using an SslStream with TcpClient which I've wrapped together in a class called SSLClient.  I keep getting the "The certificate chain was issued by an authority that is not trusted" error on the AuthenticateAsClient line.  Here is my SSLClient(Much of it started from the MSDN example of using an SslStream with TcpClient):

```
public class SSLClient
{
    public delegate void OnSSLRequestHandler(SSLRequestEvent e);

    private string _machineName;
    private string [] _serverCertFilenames;
    private string [] _serverCertPasswords;

    public event OnSSLRequestHandler OnLoaded;

    public SSLClient(
        string machineName,
        string [] serverCertFilenames,
        string [] serverCertPasswords )
    {
        _machineName = machineName;
        _serverCertFilenames = serverCertFilenames;
        _serverCertPasswords = serverCertPasswords;
    }

    public bool ValidateServerCertificate(
          object sender,
          X509Certificate certificate,
          X509Chain chain,
          SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors)
    {
       if (sslPolicyErrors == SslPolicyErrors.None)
            return true;

        // Do not allow this client to communicate with unauthenticated servers. 
        return false;
    }

    public void Load(byte[] sendData, int port = 443)  
    {
        // Create a TCP/IP client socket. 
        // machineName is the host running the server application.
        TcpClient client = new TcpClient(_machineName, port);

        // Create an SSL stream that will close the client's stream.
        SslStream sslStream = new SslStream(
            client.GetStream(), 
            false, 
            new RemoteCertificateValidationCallback (ValidateServerCertificate), 
            null
        );

        // The server name must match the name on the server certificate. 
        try 
        {
            X509Certificate2Collection xc = new X509Certificate2Collection();
            for (int i = 0; i < _serverCertFilenames.Length; i++)
            {
                string certName = _serverCertFilenames[i];
                string certPwd = _serverCertPasswords[i];

                X509Certificate2 x;
                if (certPwd != "")
                    x = new X509Certificate2(certName, certPwd);
                else
                    x = new X509Certificate2(certName);

                xc.Add(x);
            }

            sslStream.AuthenticateAsClient(_machineName, xc, SslProtocols.Ssl3, false);
        } 
        catch (AuthenticationException e)
        {
            string errMsg = "Exception: " + e.Message;


            if (e.InnerException != null)
                errMsg += ("\r\nInner exception: " + e.InnerException.Message);

            errMsg += ("\r\nAuthentication failed - closing the connection.");
            client.Close();

            // Just fires an event, ctor(success, message, response, SSLClient)
            if (OnLoaded != null)
                OnLoaded(new SSLRequestEvent(false, errMsg, null, this));

            return;
        }

        sslStream.Write(sendData);
        sslStream.Flush();

        // Read message from the server. 
        byte[] response = ReadMessage(sslStream);

        // Just fires an event, ctor(success, message, response, SSLClient)
        if (OnLoaded != null)
            OnLoaded(new SSLRequestEvent(true, "Success", response, this));

        // Close the client connection.
        client.Close();
    }

    private byte[] ReadMessage(SslStream sslStream)
    {
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();

        byte [] buffer = new byte[2048];

        int bytes = -1;
        do
        {
            bytes = sslStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

            ms.Write(buffer, 0, bytes);

        } while (bytes != 0);

        return ms.ToArray();
    }
}
```

The certificates used are one I have followed the steps for from Apple to a test mobile application I am working on, as well as 4 entrust certificates which seems are also required.  The usage of this class is as follows:

```
public void DoAPNSPush()
{
    // Build the binary data to be sent
    byte[] bin = BuildAPNSMessage();

    // These certs are uploaded to the server next to this ASPX
    // and are being found and read correctly.
    string[] certs = new string[] {
        Server.MapPath("certs") + "\\MyPFX.pfx",
        Server.MapPath("certs") + "\\my_cert_from_apple.cer",
        Server.MapPath("certs") + "\\entrust_2048_ca.cer"
    };

    string[] pwds = new string[] {
        "password",
        "",
        ""
    };

    SSLClient ssl = new SSLClient("gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com", certs, pwds);
    ssl.OnLoaded += new SSLClient.OnSSLRequestHandler(onSSLLoaded);
    ssl.Load(bin, 2195);
}

public void onSSLLoaded(SSLRequestEvent e)
{
    // We never get here, but the event has the following members:
    //      bool e.Success
    //      string e.Message
    //      byte[] e.Response
    //      SSLClient e.Client
}
```

Hopefully this isn't TLDR.  What could I be doing wrong that authentication still fails?  I have already made sure port 2195 is open on the Amazon Security Group. Additionally, I have tried other SslProtocols.Ssl3 and SslProtocols.Tls.  The CSR for apple was generated from this server and completed, the entrust certs were downloaded from their website(https://www.entrust.net/downloads/root_request.cfm#) and I just double-clicked them once on the server to install them.

Any input would be helpful

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, after working with JavaPNS for awhile I got it working, my problem was mostly with the certificate.  It wasn't until I found I needed to convert the .p12 and .cer from Apple into a new p12(Using openSSL) that Apple accepted the connection and performed the push.  Afterwards I revisted my SSLClient code and also got that working.

```
public class SSLClient
{
public delegate void OnSSLRequestHandler(SSLRequestEvent e);

private string _remoteHost;
private string [] _serverCertFilenames;
private string [] _serverCertPasswords;

public event OnSSLRequestHandler OnLoaded;

public SSLClient(string remoteHost, string [] serverCertFilenames, string [] serverCertPasswords)
{
    _remoteHost = remoteHost;
    _serverCertFilenames = serverCertFilenames;
    _serverCertPasswords = serverCertPasswords;
}

public bool ValidateServerCertificate(
      object sender,
      X509Certificate certificate,
      X509Chain chain,
      SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors)
{
    return true;
}

public void Load(byte[] sendData, int port = 443)  
{
    // Create a TCP/IP client socket. 
    TcpClient client = new TcpClient(_remoteHost, port);

    // Create an SSL stream utilizing the TcpClient
    SslStream sslStream = new SslStream(
        client.GetStream(), 
        false, 
        new RemoteCertificateValidationCallback (ValidateServerCertificate), 
        null
    );

    try 
    {
        X509Certificate2Collection xc = new X509Certificate2Collection();

        for (int i = 0; i < _serverCertFilenames.Length; i++)
        {
            X509Certificate2 x = new X509Certificate2(
                _serverCertFilenames[i],
                _serverCertPasswords[i] );

            xc.Add(x);
        }

        sslStream.AuthenticateAsClient(_remoteHost, xc, SslProtocols.Default, true);
    }
    catch (AuthenticationException e)
    {
        client.Close();
        sslStream.Close();

        if (OnLoaded != null)
            OnLoaded(new SSLRequestEvent(false, errMsg, null, this));

        return;
    }

    sslStream.Write(sendData);
    sslStream.Flush();

    // Read message from the server. 
    byte[] response = ReadMessage(sslStream);

    if (OnLoaded != null)
        OnLoaded(new SSLRequestEvent(true, "Success", response, this));

    // Close the client connection.
    client.Close();
}

private byte[] ReadMessage(SslStream sslStream)
{
    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();

    byte [] buffer = new byte[1024];

    int bytes = -1;
    do
    {
        bytes = sslStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

        ms.Write(buffer, 0, bytes);

    } while (bytes != 0);

    return ms.ToArray();
}
}
```

Usage is the same as before.  The biggest trick here was the openSSL commands needed I've got here:

```
openssl x509 -in "path_to_apple_cert.cer" -inform DER -out "path_to_an_output_Cert.pem" -outform PEM
openssl pkcs12 -nocerts -in "path_to_exported_p12_from_apple_cer.p12" -out "path_to_an_output_Key.pem" -passin pass:your_p12_password -passout pass:your_new_p12_password
openssl pkcs12 -export -inkey "path_to_an_output_Key.pem" -in "path_to_an_output_Cert.pem" -out "path_to_final_p12.p12" -passin pass:your_new_p12_password -passout pass:your_final_p12_password
```

That might look nasty - but all it's really doing is: Line 1) Taking the .CER file you got from apple and making a certificate .pem from it, Line 2) Taking the .P12 you exported from your keychain access and password protected and making a key .pem from it, then finally 3) Taking the two pems it just made and creating a new p12 from them.  THIS IS THE P12 that apple's push notification server ended up accepting from me.

Hope this helps some of you out there - my head has been spinning over certificates, pfx's, p12's, pem's, etc, etc for a week now getting this stuff working.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how the SSL code should look like in C# (I implemented this in Java), but shouldn't you pass a password with the certificate?

Comment: Oddly enough, it did accept these as-is since they were just .cer files they had no password.  I did update this to accept passwords, and passed in the .pfx with the password and it accepts that as well. I've also made sure I'm using X509Certificate2Collection and X509Certificate2 everywhere(I wasn't originally) and now I am getting a different error: "The certificate chain was issued by an authority that is not trusted." I will update my post with this, thanks.

Comment: Do you have to use the entrust certificates? In Java security, you pass the TrustManager and KeyManager certificates in two separate parameters. The TrustManager is optional. The KeyManager is initialized with the certificate you get from Apple (the p12 file). Apple only requires you to use the certificate that they issue in order for the connection to work.

Comment: I tried every variety of with and without certs and it never worked - I want to come back to it later, but I've had to set this down for now - and decided to try using a 3rd party. I went with JavaPNS and created a new certificate through apple. Always getting a handshake-failure now. Once I have more I will come back to this hopefully with an answer and some code everyone else can use if they want to.

Comment: @sidestepper If you got this error with JavaPNs, the problem is most likely the KeyStore file (I used the JavaPNs library and I know that it works when the KeyStore is OK). When you exported the certificate to a p12 file (the KeyStore), did you select both the certificate and the private key?

Comment: I had followed the instructions from Apple on generating the CSR, installing the CER, then exporting a P12 - but it seemed I was missing a step somewhere. What you're saying does seem oddly like what it could have been. I had to take an extra step with the p12 exported from my keychain into openSSL to get the p12 that ended up working. See my answer below. Thanks for the help!